# How to pipe Excel file data as string to Azure Function?

Tags: excel, file, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I'm using a Logic App to detect additions to a Sharepoint Directory. When it detects a file, it takes the file content using `Get_file_content` and sends it to my Azure function as a string. The string comes in in this format:

`PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0006\u0000\b\u0000\u0000\u0000!\u0000��1ŏ\u0001\u0000\u0000�\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0013\u0000�\u0001[Content_Types].xml ��\u0001`

which I'm not sure what the encoding is.

Is there a way to decode this to an excel document, enough to be able to resave it to the file system as a `.xlsx` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people in the future that need help with this, encode it using the `base64` function. Decoding it to the file system using `$ base64 -d -i file.txt >> out.xlsx` works.